# Angular 2 and fullscreen API

Tags: angular

I've looked trough the docs and examples, yet found no way to listen for the "onfullscreenchange" event and/or it's variants ("onwebkitfullscreenchange" etc.) on the "document" element.

What i've tried without success:

```
/*method 1*/    
host: {
      '(document:onwebkitfullscreenchange)': 'fullScreen()'
    }
/*method 2*/
    @HostListener("document:onwebkitfullscreenchange", []) fullScreen() {}
/*method 3*/
    renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'onwebkitfullscreenchange', (event) => {})
```

All of the above work with the more common events such as `onclick` event.

If you've figured out a way to integrate the `fullscreen API` with Angular 2 or have other ideas or suggestions on how to go about or attempt this, i'd be very appreciative of your help.

Edit: If you could point me to a helpful resource, that might demistify (even partially) this, i would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

**ANSWER**
`document:webkitfullscreenchange` (and so forth for the other browsers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `onfullscreenchange` event type. That's the event *handler*, so you could do (but probably shouldn't, as it's not really the "Angular way" of doing this):

```
document.onfullscreenchange = () => console.log('fullscreenchange event fired!');
```

But there is a `fullscreenchange` event, so this should work fine:

```
@HostListener("document:fullscreenchange", []) fullScreen() {}
```

Comment: The "onfullscreenchange"  is the standard, but if you look at the documentation for the API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API you'll see that each browser implements a different eventhandler, not the standard, unless, i'm reading that wrong.
That aside, i've just tested your suggestion it does not work. Perhaps i am missing something but i can't figure it out.

Comment: So it's actually browser prefixed -> for chrome `document:webkitfullscreenchange`. But it works. For some reason however, the event is not triggered if you fullscreen with the F11, default keybinding. You have trigger it manually, on F11/ESC via listeners on their respective keycodes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an sample for check fullscreen or exit fullscreen use a boolean variable.

```
 @HostListener('document:fullscreenchange', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:webkitfullscreenchange', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:mozfullscreenchange', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:MSFullscreenChange', ['$event'])
  fullscreenmode(){

    if(this.toggleClass == 'ft-minimize'){
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-maximize';
    }
    else{
      this.toggleClass = 'ft-minimize';
    }
    console.log(this.toggleClass)
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullscreen-closefullscreen-check?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('document:fullscreenchange')
@HostListener('document:webkitfullscreenchange')
@HostListener('document:mozfullscreenchange')
@HostListener('document:MSFullscreenChange')
onScreenModeСhange() {
    //Do stuff
}
```