# Restrict user to exit the fullscreen mode in Angular 8

Tags: angular, google-chrome, event-handling, fullscreenchange

I'm using **Angular v8** for my application. My problem is I want to **restrict** the user from exiting the fullscreen mode. I have looked various solution on Stack Overflow and found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36795728/5893995).
Below is my code where I have tried to implement this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.attachEventListeners();
 }

 attachEventListeners() {
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', this.onFullScreenChange(), false);
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', this.onFullScreenChange(), false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', this.onFullScreenChange(), false);    
  }

  onFullScreenChange() {
    const fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement;

    console.log(fullscreenElement);
    // if in fullscreen mode fullscreenElement won't be null
  }
```

But this code is throwing an error:

```
ExamComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined
    at nodeValue (core.js:27236)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ExamComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at handleEvent (core.js:38098)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:39716)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:39352)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:25818)
    at core.js:37030
    at platform-browser.js:1789
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
```

I don't know if there is something using `@HostListener` for angular is there for handling this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question is a bit old, but probably it will be helpful for someone else — previously I faced with the same question and found following solution with `@HostListener`:

```
  @HostListener("document:fullscreenchange", []) 
  fullScreen() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
        console.log(`Entered full-screen mode.`);
    } else {
        console.log('Leaving full-screen mode.');
    }
  }
```

from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42282972/1362723.